# PyQt5 receivers

Tags: python, pyqt5

I wanted to port a PyQt4 app of mine to PyQt5 and came across a subtle problem.

At some point I check if a custom `QThread` object (`worker`) has still some specific signal connected, which I have done in PyQt4 like so (exemplary code):

```
if worker.receivers(PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL("signalFinished(QString,QString)")):
    do_stuff()
```

Is there any way to do this in PyQt5? The [PyQt5 reference](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qobject.html?highlight=qobject#PyQt5.QtCore.QObject) is not very helpful, and always leeds me to the [C++ reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#receivers), where it is still the same behaviour.

Of course there is a more 'pythonic' solution using a try-except-pass block instead of an if statement, but I am still wondering for the 'PyQt signal' way.

Comment: It's maybe not that, but did you try with the new style signals ? This notation seem to be deprecated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new-style syntax, the equivalent code would simply be:

```
if worker.receivers(worker.signalFinished[str, str])):
    do_stuff()
```

Comment: Wow, dead-simple indeed. Thanks a lot! (shame I didn't figured this myself...)